# Footer width and position queries

Tags: css, width, footer

for some reason I can't get my footer to stick to the bottom of the page

EDIT: I am trying to keep it at the bottom of the *page*, not the bottom of the *window*

and the even though I have set it to width:100% it seems to be 100% of the width of the previous div rather than 100% of the page.

Here is the jsFiddle of the entire page :  http://jsfiddle.net/eehSa/1/

The css code I am using for the footer is:

```
#footer {height:50px; width:100%; background-color:red; position:absolute; bottom:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Set `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` for `footer`</strike>

EDIT:

Apply a CSS Reset `*{padding:0;margin:0;}` then change the `position` of the `footer` to `relative` and remove the `top` from the container.

Demo:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nw7ej/show/

Comment: Adding position: fixed means that the footer is now always in view, I am trying to position it at the bottom of the page so that it is only visible when it is scrolled to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the left value `left: 0;` and a fixed position  `position:fixed;`

```
 #footer #footer {height:50px; width:100%; background-color:red; position:fixed; bottom:0px;left: 0;}
```

## [live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eehSa/3/)

[image]

## UPDATE

```
#container {height:100%;
position: relative;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 0 20% 5%;/* add some magrin-bottom*/
background-color: white;
top: 80px;
}
```

on the body :

```
   body {background-color:lightgray; padding:0;margin:0;}/* add padding and margin*/
```

position relatve

```
 #footer {height:50px; width:100%; background-color:red; position:relative; bottom:0px;left: 0;clear:both;}
```

## [Live Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/eehSa/6/)

Comment: This keeps the footer fixed to the bottom of the window, meaning it is always in view. I am trying to position it at the bottom of the page so that it is only visible when you scroll down to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's some steps you need to do for that, 
Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/eehSa/4/

```
html,body{                       /** Add new style to html,body */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color:lightgray;
    position: relative;         /** New */ 
    height: auto;               /** New */
    min-height: 100%;           /** New */
    padding-bottom: 75px;       /** New, equal to footer height + x */
}
#footer {
    height:50px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color:red; 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0;                    /** New */
}
```